# Count of current values in column

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, counting, google-sheets-query

I'd like to know count of current value in column.

```
+--------------+---------------------+--+------------+------------+
|              |                     |  | 1st column | 2nd column |
+--------------+---------------------+--+------------+------------+
| How many 'A' | (there should be 1) |  | A          | B          |
+--------------+---------------------+--+------------+------------+
| How many 'B' | (there should be 2) |  | B          | B          |
+--------------+---------------------+--+------------+------------+
|              |                     |  | B          | A          |
+--------------+---------------------+--+------------+------------+
```

I try to do this in Google Sheets.

Comment: You can use counta

Comment: @user11982798 I edited my first topic, I don't think COUNTA is good way.

Comment: What did you mean count of current value?

Comment: how do you want to count it? by rows? by column? or by columns?

Comment: CountA can be combined with filter, for example countA(filter(c2:D2, c2:D2="A"))

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
=QUERY({D2:D; E2:E}, 
 "select Col1,count(Col1) 
  where Col1 is not null 
  group by Col1 
  label count(Col1)''", 0)
```